# Use triangle normals in OpenGL to get vertex normals

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I have a list of vertices and their arrangement into triangles as well as the per-triangle normalized normal vectors.

Ideally, I'd like to do as little work as possible in somehow converting the (triangle,normal) pairs into (vertex,vertex_normal) pairs that I can stick into my VAO. Is there a way for OpenGL to deal with the face normals directly? Or do I have to keep track of each face a given vertex is involved in (which more or less happens already when I calculate the index buffers) and then manually calculate the averaged normal at the vertex?

Also, is there a way to skip per-vertex normal calculation altogether and just find a way to inform the fragment shader of the face-normal directly?

Edit: I'm using something that should be portable to ES devices so the fixed-function stuff is  unusable

Comment: Are you asking how to compute per-vertex normals in a shader, or how to use face normals for triangles without having to duplicate position data?

Comment: Well I currently have a bunch of face normals and I'd rather not calculate the vertex normals on the CPU if I can help it. 

Also since I have the face normals (and I'm not doing normal mapping), interpolating the vertex normals to find the fragment normals seems like a waste.

Comment: "*I'd rather not calculate the vertex normals on the CPU if I can help it.*" Why not? They don't change unless the positions change. The CPU is the best place to calculate static data. Also, it's not clear if you want to use the per-face normals on the vertices or if you want to compute *real* vertex normals to create a smooth surface. Are you flat-shading or not?

Comment: I'd rather not calculate them at all if I can get the GPU to deal with them for me. I initially want to use flat shading so it seems pointless to calculate them and interpolate an approximation but I guess I'd have to give up my index buffer if I do that (And dump a whole bunch more vertices to the gpu) but for more complicated lighting models I have to spend CPU time to calculate the appropriate vertex normals.

Is there a way to get flat shading with index buffers without repeating all of my vertices?

Comment: "*I'd rather not calculate them at all if I can get the GPU to deal with them for me.*" Why? Doing it once on the CPU is free as far as your frame rendering time is concerned. It's a one-time initialization cost, compared to taking time on each frame for the GPU to do the computations.

Comment: Right now my CPU has its hands full simulating some stuff but I guess I could cache them if I was forced to calculate them. Another issue is that STL files can't hold per-vertex normals so persisting the mesh in an exchange friendly format will be a pain

Comment: @nimish These are not things that need to persist, to be honest. You can simply pre-process the mesh data before creating a vertex buffer to insert per-vertex normals. You might have to do this anyway depending on whether you want smoothed (e.g. averaged across edges) or discrete (unique per-facet) normals. Since this happens at load-time, it is not going to affect your simulation performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't necessarily speak as to the latest full-fat OpenGL specifications but certainly in ES you're going to have to do the work yourself.

Although the normal was modal under the old fixed pipeline like just about everything else, it was attached to each vertex. If you opted for the flat shading model then GL would use the colour at the first vertex on the face across the entire thing rather than interpolating it. There's no way to recreate that behaviour under ES.

Attributes are per vertex and uniforms are — at best — per batch. In ES there's no way to specify per-triangle properties and there's no stage of the rendering pipeline where you have an overview of the geometry when you could distribute them to each vertex individually. Each vertex is processed separately, varyings are interpolation and then each fragment is processed separately.